# Setting display styles externally causes an onclick() event TWO clicks to initialise

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why do we have to set `display: none;` inline on the HTML instead of externally for the `onclick()` event to work on the first click, on the first time.

With it set externally the code worked but took two clicks to initialise, One to set the event handler and one to fire the event handler. My code **was** this:

```js
function submenu() {
  Menu = document.getElementById('menu');
  sub = document.getElementById('sub');

  function display() {
    if (sub.style.display === 'none') {
      sub.style.display = "inline-block";
    } else {
      sub.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  Menu.addEventListener('click', display);
}

function pageLoad() {
  submenu();
}
```

```css
nav {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: -60%;
  left: 24%;
  display: block;
  width: 33%;
  height: 20%;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

nav ul li {
  width: 100%;
  color: #888;
  z-index: 0;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #888;
}

#sub {
  width: 120%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 230%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#sub li {
  margin-top: 3px;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 2;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li id="menu"> - Menu - </li>
    <ul id="sub">
      <li><a href="#methods">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#aftercare">Aftercare</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact Me</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

It would take two clicks to initialise and then work, but after changing the following lines it works first click every time:

HTML changes:

```
<nav id="menu">
<ul id="sub" style="display: none;">
```

CSS Changes:

```
#sub {
        width: 120%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 230%;
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: rgba(51,51,51,0.8);
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

And for the javascript code, i added the function to window.onload like:

```
window.onload = pageLoad;
function pageLoad() {
    submenu();
}
```

So unless i change the style `display: none;` to inline CSS, it still took two clicks.
I would like to better understand the process involved as to why this happens. I have tried looking for an explanation of this on google but received nothing.

Comment: Also please note that your html is not correct. You have terminated the `li` - `<li id="menu"> - Menu - </li>` and then further down you terminate it again

Comment: Thanks @KScandrett I missed that :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting the style for `display` in CSS, then to start out with `sub.style.display` will be an empty string, however if you set it on the element using the style attribute, then it will have the value you give it. You can get around this by checking whether the value is an empty string, but then you have to work out what that means for your application (based on what the initial value is in your CSS).

I'd like to propose an alternative here that should serve you well for other scenarios too and doesn't require you to change the style attribute, instead relying on changing the class of an element.

If you were to add some CSS to hide submenus by default and a class that can toggle the menu to be visible:

```
nav ul ul { 
    display: none; 
}
nav .active {
    display: block;
}
```

With the following JS to toggle the class

```
var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
var sub = document.getElementById('sub');
function toggleMenu(){
    sub.classList.toggle('active');
}
menu.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
```

This way you could easily adjust your code to do this for multiple sub menus, so here is yet another example that is slightly more generic and allows you to have multiple menus and submenus.

e.g.

HTML

```
<nav class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="parent"> - Menu 1 -
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#sub">sub menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#sub">sub menu 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parent"> - Menu 2 -
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#sub">sub menu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#sub">sub menu 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.menu ul ul { display: none; }
.menu .active {
    display: block;
}
```

JS

```
var menus = document.querySelectorAll('.menu');

function toggleMenu(e){

    var target = e.target;
    // only care about clicks on parent list items.
    if (target.className.indexOf('parent') === -1) {
        return;
    }
    // use querySelector to find the first <ul> inside this parent <li>
    var submenu = target.querySelector('ul');

    if (submenu) {
        submenu.classList.toggle('active');
    }
}

// add a click handler to each menu
menus.forEach(function(menu) {
    menu.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
});
```